# Anaconda not able to installed Spyder in Environment

Tags: anaconda, spyder

[image]Current version of Anaconda is not able to install the Spyder in a virtual Environment. I have tried it using Anaconda Prompt as well Anaconda Navigator

Is this some kind of bug. I updated the python 3.6 to 3.7 and the mentioned problem is prevailing since then

I have tried using Anaconda Navigator > Environment >  Create > used App install to install Spyder version of 3.3.3

```
conda install -c conda-forge spyder 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 spyder 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/beta spyder
```

Comment: You should reinstall Anaconda and try again. Mixing things from conda-forge and default channels is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Already did it. Twice, in fact.. still the same error is faced..

Comment: Please post your problem [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/). You could more help there.